# Constant "ImportError: No module named..."

Tags: python, importerror

I'm kind of new on Python, and I'm trying to do some things but I keep having this "ImportError: No module named ..." error (in different cases) Now I'm trying a tutorial of automated testing with Python but in the first example it didn't run because it give me the same kind of error "ImportError: No module named mobydick".

It's important to say that all the times that I got that error (like four or five different cases) I checked and the modules that I was referring are there, I think this could be something about configuration maybe that I can`t get now, I have been looked a lot on Google and here on Stackoverflow and haven't find a solution yet.

The structure of the tutorial code (it comes with the tutorial, it's supposed to work, is this:

```
code
-mobydick
--_init_.py
--word_counter.py
-tests_unittest
--test_unit_test.py
```

I'm working on Mac environment

Answer (score 0):

Require `__init__.py` file for every directory.

```
code
-__init__py
-mobydick
--__init__py
--word_counter.py
-tests_unittest
-__init__py
--test_unit_test.py
```

Comment: I tried that on the tutorial project but didn't worked, also I take a look on the previous project where I had the same error and all them have an __init__.py file (the old ones are projects that work in other computers but In mine I keep having the "importerror" error.)